# What is the difference between "time overrun" and "time limit exceeded"?

Tags: process, operating-system, kernel

My class and I cannot come to a consensus on if there is a difference between "Time Limit Exceeded" and "Time Overrun".  We are reading, "*Operating Systems*" by Stallings and don't see anywhere these two are differentiated beyond the descriptions below.

You can see the list of "**Reasons for Process Termination**" on page two of [this PDF](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/kerola/kj2/stal-01_slides_figs/T3-Vertical.pdf).

From that list:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Reason              | Explanation                                                                                           |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Time limit exceeded | The process has run longer than the specified total time limit.                                       |
|                     | There are a number of possibilities for the type of time that is measured.                            |
|                     | These include total elapsed time ("wall clock time"), amount of time spent executing,                 |
|                     | and, in the case of an interactive process, the amount of time since the user last provided any input.|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Time overrun        | The process has waited longer than a specified maximum for a certain event to occur.                  |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So far, the best response I've seen is "time limit exceeded" is how long a process is allowed to use the CPU (an OS control) and "time overrun" is when a process has waited too long for an event to occur (a control within a process).

Is there a distinction and, if so, which component makes the determination to terminate - kernel or process?  Is it simply that one has "run" longer than it is permitted and one has "waited" longer than is permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “Time overrun” is what is usually known as a **timeout**.  You’re right that a wait that might result in a timeout is under the control of the process.

Your book is obviously describing very old systems; in modern ones, a timeout would rarely (if ever) be considered a reason to terminate a process (although of course any process might *choose* to exit when one occurs).  Limits on a process’s total run time, on the other hand, are a common (if optional) feature: Unix systems send `SIGXCPU` to a process whose CPU time exceeds a [configurable limit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html).

Comment: For clarity, I think it would be worth changing "overrun" before the link to the IEEE doc to "exceeded".  Since I'm struggling to keep the two straight, I think it would help if your first paragraph referred to "overrun" and your second referred to "exceeded", then it will help to further reduce any confusion.  All the same, thanks for the response.  Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @harperville: Sure; I wondered about the word choice, but thought “exceeded” looked out of place there.  I tried a different phrasing just now—but you could have just edited it yourself.